# Intent matching stops working and works again after manual train

Tags: dialogflow-es

Recently we started to observer problem with Dialogflow: We have an agent with ~200 intents. Everything works as expected, but then, all of the sudden, without changing anything in the agent, intent that was matching with some input, just stops matching with the exact same input. The only way to fix it is to go and manually click train and then it works again.

Any thoughts or does anyone had the same issue?